# Getting Screen width and height

Tags: objective-c

Im creating a new subview in XCode using CGRectmake. This I can do fine. But I would like to make the size of the new view 10 pixels less than the screen width. I normally work with Java and would use screen.width-10 to do this. But with ObjC in Xcode I'm not sure how to and couldn't find the info i needed. This what I have so far it creates a box on a button tap but i would like to change the width from 100 to screen width - 10.

```
//Info Button
-(IBAction) buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    // create a new UIView
    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)];

    // do something, e.g. set the background color to red
    newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // add the new view as a subview to an existing one (e.g. self.view)
    [self.view addSubview:newView];

    // release the newView as -addSubview: will retain it
    [newView release];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use the search function before asking very obvious questions

Answer (score 11):

```
float height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height

float width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
```

Comment: It works in Cordova plugins too.

Answer (score 5):

The screen height / width can be retrieved from:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height

[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
```